# Get my output( from my apex class) and assign it to a flow variable

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, invocablevariable

I have an apex class that returns a list of records/response as an output.

```
public class KnowledgeArticleLookup {

   @InvocableMethod(label='Get Knowledge Articles' description='Gets knowledge article results')
   public static List<List<Response>> getMyArticles (List<Request> req){
    List<KnowledgeArticleVersion> Articles = new List<KnowledgeArticleVersion>();

    if(req[0].varType1 == 'Global Info'){
      if(req[0].varType2 == 'Location'){
            articles = [SELECT Id,
                              Title 
                             FROM KnowledgeArticleVersion 
                             WHERE PublishStatus='online' 
                             WITH DATA CATEGORY 
                             Global_Knowledge__c AT Location__c];
      }
    }
    List<List<Response>> outputResponse = new List<List<Response>>();
    List<Response> responses = new List<Response>();
    for(KnowledgeArticleVersion kav: articles) {
         Response response = new Response();
         response.articleversionId = kav.Id;
         response.articleTitle = kav.Title;
         responses.add(response);
    }
    outputResponse.add(responses);
   return outputResponse;
  }

  public class Request {
    @InvocableVariable(required=true)
     public String varType1;
    @InvocableVariable(required=true)
     public String varType2;
   }

   public class Response {
      @InvocableVariable
       public String articleversionId;
      @InvocableVariable
       public String articleTitle;
   }
}
```

when I debug my flow, my apex class returns the result as follow:
[image]

I was wondering how I can assign my articleversionId to a flow collection variable, knowing that my flow apex action doesn't give me the possibility to store my output variable (screenshot below).
[image]

Comment: Under advanced, if you check the "Manually assign variables" checkbox, it should allow you to assign.

Comment: Hi @Aditya,
Thanks for your response.
it does but i can not assign a collection variable

Comment: May be you should try returning a list from Apex. `global List<String> articleVersionId`

Comment: I do return a List<List<Response>>

Comment: Try adding the code to the question itself, and may be elaborate a bit on current behavior and expected behavior.

Comment: Hi @AdityaNaag, I've added my apex class to the original post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128378/discussion-between-aditya-naag-and-user52619).

Comment: sure...
thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the Response inner class to a dedicated class so that it can be picked up as an Apex-Defined type by a flow.

```
global class Response {
    @AuraEnabled @InvocableVariable
    global String articleversionId;

    @AuraEnabled @InvocableVariable
    global String articleTitle;
}
```

You can then define a Resource with this new Apex Type.

[image]

and finally, you can assign the response from your invocable action to this resource.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that you're returning a single string:
public String varType1;

...and you can't automatically assign a single string to a collection of strings.

As Aditya proposes in the comments, you can change the output type to return a collection:

```
   public class Response {
      @InvocableVariable
       public List<String> articleversionIdList;
      @InvocableVariable
       public String articleTitle;
   }
```

then, in your code, initialize your list and push your actual id into it:

```
List<String> articleversionIdList = new List<String>();
articleversionIdList.add(articleversionId);
```

Now your id is loaded into a collection and you can assign it to another collection variable.